# Slideshow Background of the body of the website

Tags: javascript, css

How can I apply a set of images as slideshow background of the BODY of my website? Should I use `body.style.background = imgarray[i]` in JS?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a jquery plugin like "cycle". Instructions here...

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/begin.html

1. Include jQuery library
2. Include Cycle plugin
3. Apply to your slideshow like..

   ```
   $('#your-gallery-container').cycle('fade');
   ```